# How to get same element 2nd time came in same parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to select same element came 2nd time in the same parent element using xslt.

I am displaying my xml..

```
<parent>
            <a>0001</a>
            <b>05</b>
            <c>20160825</c>
            <d>9463</d>
            <e>anders skov petersen</e>
            <f></f>
            <g></g>
            <h></h>
            <i></i>
            <a>0002</a>
            <b>05</b>
            <c>20160825</c>
            <d>9463</d>
            <e>anders skov petersen</e>
            <f></f>
            <g></g>
            <h></h>
            <i></i>
        </parent>
```

In my xml , a , b, c and all other elements came twice . So If I have to fetch value of element which came 2nd time in XSLT then could any1 please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for duplicates solely based on the element name? Or on the element content? Can there be complex content in the form of e.g. `<j><foo>bar</foo></j>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the second a with the following XPath-Expression

```
/parent/a[2]
```

This is the short form of

```
/parent/a[position()=2]
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to identify same element (name, not the content) appearing twice within same parent:

**Input XML:**

```
<parent>
   <a>0001</a>
   <b>05</b>
   <c>20160825</c>
   <d>9463</d>
   <e>anders skov petersen</e>
   <f></f>
   <g></g>
   <h></h>
   <i></i>
   <a>0002</a>
   <b>05</b>
   <c>20160825</c>
   <d>9463</d>
   <e>anders skov petersen</e>
   <f></f>
   <g></g>
   <h></h>
   <i></i>
   <j>New element</j>
</parent>
```

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kDuplicate" match="*[generate-id(parent::*) = 
                                 generate-id(current()/parent::*)]" use="name()"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[key('kDuplicate', name())[2]]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[key('kDuplicate', name())[2]]">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:** (element `j` not appearing, as it is appearing only once within its parent)

```
<parent>
  <a>0001</a>
  <b>05</b>
  <c>20160825</c>
  <d>9463</d>
  <e>anders skov petersen</e>
  <f/>
  <g/>
  <h/>
  <i/>
  <a>0002</a>
  <b>05</b>
  <c>20160825</c>
  <d>9463</d>
  <e>anders skov petersen</e>
  <f/>
  <g/>
  <h/>
  <i/>
</parent>
```